# Firebase Rules to register users and allow users to login

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase real time database in my android app. I want users to register in my app with some checking and validation. if i set the rules such as:

```
{
  "rules": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

The users who have already created an account can sign-in but the new users are unable to register , here is my data,

```
{"Users": {
    "04Al23ye5KTI4dVerYn": {
      "email": "abc@gmail.com",
      "image": " ",
       "name":""}}}
```

I am also authenticating users using email verification of firebase in which user receives a mail when registering in app to verify please guide me.

[here is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8Yxx.png)

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/products/auth) to implement authentication in your app instead of a database.

Comment: Please see the picture. Issue is due to rule of .write the data of new users are not been saved because it only write when there is auth. Please guide

Comment: Firebase auth and Firebase realtime database are 2 separate services. To implement auth in your application you should use Authentication which seems to be enabled in your case but you don't have to do anything in the database. Checkout [Getting started with Firebase Authentication](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rbuSx1yEgV8&t=800s)

Comment: Correct. i am saying that my system is working like this that user will go to register activity and fill the details and when submit the information, that information is not being stored because of .write(auth != null) if i do (write = true) then the data save into the database and then user receive a verifiaction mail from firebase auth to confirm the account and so to login into the app. What should i do. because i want to make firebase rules that data should be saved after auth or saved by doing some validation aur checking.

Answer (score 0):

firebase already has authentication system inside.

---

browse this [*firebase-auth*](https://firebase.google.com/products/auth?gclid=CjwKCAjw7IeUBhBbEiwADhiEMQG_k3QRTwued5nbUkTmzMI2tOAplbGYEjLSfl8zuT7oYduZxZonLBoCBRQQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Comment: You are right, but i am saying that my system is working like this that user will go to register activity and fill the details and when submit the information, that information is not being stored because of .write(auth != null) if i do (write = true) then the data save into the database and then user receive a verifiaction mail from firebase auth to confirm the account and so to login into the app. What should i do. because i want to make firebase rules that data should be saved after auth or saved by doing some validation aur checking.

Comment: read these document  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#send_a_user_a_verification_email

Comment: do not use real time database for authentication. There is already photo_url,email,display_name,uid,password in the auth system. I recommend you to browse this page to manage this information: Web: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users.    android: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users